# Dojo fade animations not working

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

Alright I've been trying to learn Dojo here today and I just can't seem to figure out why I can't fade in my elements. What I'm doing here is loading a set of images from a json object and putting them in the DOM. I then want to fade them in one at a time using an array and the shift method. This is a working plugin I wrote in jQuery and am using as a crash course for Dojo. The wierd thing is that I can't get the fade animation to work at all, even if I strip away the array and just try to target a single DOM element, but if I paste in one of the examples from [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/fx.html#dojo-base-fx-fadein) directly into my webpage, that works.

Here's the code:

```
define([
    "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/request", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-style"
],      
    function(query, domClass, dom, request, fx, on, domAttr){

        var images = new Array(); //The array object created from the XML file
        var cur_first = 0; //Current first image, used as a counter to determine which images should be shown
        var running = true; //Flag to prevent multiple firings or next/prev
        var display_num = 4; //Num of images displayed at a time

        request.get('../../javascript/json/rotator_images.js',{handleAs:'json'}).then(
                function(response){
                    for(i=0; i < response.images.image.length; i++){
                        var src = response.images.image[i].src;
                        var title = response.images.image[i].title;
                        var desc = response.images.image[i].desc;
                        var thumb = response.images.image[i].thumb;
                        images[i]={src: src, title: title, desc: desc, thumb: thumb};
                    }
                    load_images();
                }
            );

        function load_images(){
            for(i=0; i < images.length; i++){
                if(i >= cur_first && i < cur_first+display_num){
                    dojo.create("div", {
                        innerHTML:"<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='"+images[i].src+"'><img src='"+images[i].thumb+"' /></a>",
                        className:"r_image",
                        style:{opacity:'0'},
                        id:"r_image_"+(i+1)
                    },dojo.byId("images_wrap"));
                }
            }
            display_images();
        }

        function remainder(){
            //Find the remaining images left at the end inside our display_num control so we can determine when to start back at 0 or jump to the end
            var flr = Math.floor(images.length / display_num)
            return images.length - (flr*display_num);
        }       

        query("#arrow_r").on("click", function(){
            if(running == false){
                running = true;
                if(cur_first < images.length - remainder()){
                    cur_first = cur_first+display_num;
                }else{
                    cur_first = 0;
                }
                hide_images();
            }
        })

        query("#arrow_l").on("click", function(){
            if(running == false){
                running = true;
                if(cur_first > 1){
                    cur_first = cur_first-display_num
                    hide_images();
                }else{
                    cur_first = images.length - remainder();
                    hide_images();
                }
            }
        })


        function display_images(){
            var images_arr = [];
            dojo.query(".r_image").forEach(function(node) {
                images_arr.push(node);
            });
            function fadeThemIn(images_arr) {
                if (images_arr.length > 0) {
                    var currentImg = images_arr.shift();
                    var fadeArgs = {
                        node: currentImg,
                        duration: 200,
                    };
                    fx.fadeIn(fadeArgs).play();
                }else{
                    running = false;
                }
            }
            fadeThemIn(images_arr)
        }

    }
);
```

Sorry about just dumping the entire code into here but I figure it has to be something with Dojo's AMD amd how the modules are being loaded (which I find a headache at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AMD dependency injections are going to cause your `fx` call to fail.

You're asking for:

```
"dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/request", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-style"
```

but mapping them to:

```
query, domClass, dom, request, fx, on, domAttr
```

That is, your `query` variable will get the `dojo/query` module, `domClass` will get given `dojo/dom-class`, `dom` will get given `dojo/domReady!`, `request` will get `dojo/request` and your `fx` variable will be given the `dojo/json` module, so `fx.fadeIn` won't work.

You need to make sure that the modules you're asking for, and the variables you're getting them in as, match up, one by one.  You can ask for more modules than you want to map to variables, but any such modules (`dojo/domReady!` is a good example) need to go at the end.

So, a good header for you might be:

```
define([
    // Modules I actually want, and have variables for:
    "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/request", "dojo/json", "dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-style",

    // Modules I want to be loaded, but don't have variables for:
    "dojo/domReady!"],      
    function(query, domClass, request, JSON, fx, on, domAttr, domStyle) {
```

I don't know whether that'll be *sufficient* to get your sample working completely, but matching up the modules is definitely your immediate problem.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense! I knew it had to be something with the AMD dependencies as I just about exhausted every other possibility. I'm finding it a bit of a hassle coming from jQuery but I definitely see the immediate advantages of it with large scale web applications that deal with a lot of traffic. Let me try rewriting the header now and see what happens.

Comment: Yes! It's working. Thank you my man, and thanks for clearing this up for me as well. They really should emphasize this necessity in the documentation for skimmers who like to jump in head first such as myself lol.